# Движок Медиавики: как убрать страницы-перенаправления из поиска по сайту?

Tags: mediawiki

Движок Медиавики: как убрать страницы-перенаправления из поиска по сайту?

В поиске по сайту при начале набора, к примеру, слова "страница" выходят варианты "страницу", "странице", "страницей", хотя все они являются перенаправлениями для "страница". Можно ли убрать их из поиска?

Comment: Посмотрите эти ссылки: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/rMW7e8c48ac3d11cff93c48b9c380897019eda225bd, https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T204089, https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T90807, https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Ujc6zwhx1t17u01g. Прогноз неблагоприятный.

Comment: Спасибо. Будем убирать редиректы